# KeyError when using dango_get_or_create

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm using Factory Boy 2.4.1, Django 1.4.11 and python 2.7 with the following factory:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
            model = auth.models.User
            django_get_or_create = ('Bob',)
    username = 'Dan'
```

And every time I try to create a user with the factory I get:

```
KeyError: 'Bob'
```

I've tried putting an existing key into the `django_get_or_create` field with no success. What's going wrong?

WHat's going wrong, as the comment says, is that it should read `django_get_or_create = ('username',)` ; I.e. a key of the class, not of the database.

Comment: Tuple of `django_get_or_create` consists of fields of model. `Bob` is not a field, what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yep, got it just before this by actually reading and understanding what was meant by "key" in the code. Been a numpty. The line should read `django_get_or_create = ('username')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django_get_or_create = ('username')` as in the docs where `'username'` is a key to the model, not to the database. Changing `'Bob'` to a field in the model is the solution. Thanks to the comments.